# Best way to point to vector members received as function parameters

Tags: c++

First time I'm posting to stack so if I'm not following the correct procedure, instruct me to do better and I will.

Ok, I have quite a big project with lots of classes and I cannot share code at this point, but if necessary I will write a dummy file to further explain. Hopefully I will be clear enough without that.

I have this class method that receives as params a vector: *std::vector< myClass > &objects_1*. 
Some of these will be bound (logically) to other objects in the class. The important thing to keep in mind is that I have to modify some of the received objects_1 without using the vector indexing (as it may change along the way)

Also unfortunately it is relevant for the function to have this exact signature.

The way I do it now is by having several pointers initialized with nullptr that, sooner or later  point to elements of the objects_1 vector.

My questions are: is this a bad practice? Do I have to delete the pointer or does the destructor takes care of this? Is there a better way to do this? I tried std::shared_ptr but as someone pointed out these are intended more for allocating memory dynamically.

Comment: Will any outside code be adding or removing elements to/from the vector?

Comment: Pointers to single elements of a vector will become invalid if the vector is resized.

Comment: Also, only `delete` what you `new` (or `delete[]` what you `new[]`). Just because you have a pointer doesn't mean you must pass it to `delete`.

Comment: @Galik it does, yes.

Comment: It is hard to comment on invisible code but this all sounds a bit dodgy. You have an object that stores information about the location of external objects whose locations are likely to change.

Comment: I have probably explained this poorly, but the size of the vector changes before or after the function is used, not during, so it's not an issue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the response, I suspected it but was very unsure. Thanks for confirmation. Despite my poor explanation, your answer is all I need to know right now. Thank you !

Comment: It is not the function that is the problem it is the other objects in your class keeping references to elements of the vector. Once the vector changes those references may become invalid.